# clone spring boot , maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven

hey guys i'm new in `microservices` development and there is a project that I liked to clone from `github` and run it in my computer but it does not work.

This is the link : https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/spring-boot-microservices-new.

I use intellij as iditor.

the error is :
error: release version 16 not supported

Language level is invalid or missing in pom.xml. Current project `JDK` is 14. Specify language level in product-service

Comment: To build a project which `error: release version 16 not supported` needs to use at lease JDK16+...

Comment: Which version of java you have installed in your computer? If it is above 16 then you can try building the project from outside intellij. For example, build it via termina/command prompt.

Comment: Your pom claims java 17, so please use that at least..

Comment: what does `mvn -v` tell you regarding your java configuration